# How to download all images from a directory using wget?

Tags: wget

I am new to wget.Let's get straight to the question. I want to download all images from a website directory. The directory contains no index file. The image name follows a pattern like `ABCXXXX` where `XXXX`= any four digit number. So how to download all images under the directory?

[image: Demo]

I've tried

`wget -p http://www.example.com`

but it's downloading an `index.html` file instead of multiple images.

Comment: maybe this link would help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179008/wget-download-pics-with-particular-url-string

Answer (score 4):

Using wget:

```
wget -r -A "*.jpg" http://example.com/images/
```

Using cURL:

```
curl "http://example.com/images/ABC[0000-9999].jpg" -o "ABC#1.jpg"
```

According to [man curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> You can specify multiple URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets
>   within braces as in:
>
> http://site.{one,two,three}.com
>
> or you can get sequences of alphanumeric series by using [] as in:
>
> ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[1-100].txt
>
> ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[001-100].txt (with leading zeros)
>
> ftp://ftp.letters.com/file[a-z].txt

And explanation for `#1`:

> **-o, --output `<file>`**
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to
>   fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the
>    specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current
>   string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
>
> `curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"`
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> `curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"`
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.
>
> See also the --create-dirs option to create the local directories
>   dynamically. Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) will force
>   the output to be done to stdout.

Comment: I want to accomplish this task through wget. @izidor

Comment: the wget solution downloaded  an `index.html` instead of the images.